# Why does calling Vec::resize before calling Vec::set_len cause the Vec to have data?

Tags: arrays, vector, rust, slice

I have a problem that I do not understand:

```
fn cipher_with(key: &[u8], data: &[u8]) -> Vec<u8> {
    let data_len = 16;

    let mut data = data.to_vec();
    data.resize(data_len, 2);

    let mut output = Vec::<u8>::with_capacity(data_len);
    unsafe { output.set_len(data_len) }

    output
}

fn main() {
    let key = "blabla".as_bytes();
    let data = "lorem ipsum.".as_bytes();
    println!("{:?}", cipher_with(&key, &data));
}
```

This prints:

> [108, 111, 114, 101, 109, 32, 105, 112, 115, 117, 109, 46, 0, 0, 0, 0]

But how is it done? I never gave this value to `output`.

Comment: "*I never gave this value to `output`*" => correct. In fact, you never gave any data to `output`. Neither `with_capacity()` nor `set_len()` initializes the memory, that's why the latter is even marked as `unsafe`. Why do you expect `output` to hold any useful data? [By the way: welcome to StackOverflow! If you have any questions about this format, just ask here in the comments]

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt is it just a coincidence that it contains `lorem ipsum.`?

Comment: @zerkms Wow, I haven't noticed that. The answer is probably what Francis said below. But it had me go "wat" for a moment... °_°

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt their answer does not sound convincing, since `.resize` is supposed to be in-place. Especially when you downsize it.

Comment: If someone files a documentation issue - please put a link here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add some details to [Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43058069/155423), check out this annotated version:

```
fn cipher_with(key: &[u8], data: &[u8]) -> Vec<u8> {
    let data_len = 16;

    let mut data = data.to_vec();
    println!("{:?}", data.as_ptr());
    data.resize(data_len, 2);
    println!("{:?}", data.as_ptr());

    let mut output = Vec::<u8>::with_capacity(data_len);
    println!("{:?}", output.as_ptr());
    unsafe { output.set_len(data_len) }

    output
}
```

```
0x7fa6dba27000
0x7fa6dba1e0c0
0x7fa6dba27000
```

When the first vector is created, it has a length of 12. When it's resized to 16, a new allocation is made and the data copied. This is likely due to the implementation of the allocator, which usually chunks allocations into buckets. 16 would be a reasonable bucket size.

When the second vector is created, the allocator hands back the same pointer that the first vector just gave up. Since nothing else has changed this memory in the mean time, it still contains whatever data was in `data`.

Answer (score 3):

You are using unsafe Rust, which can give you unpredictable results.

In this particular case, you are extending the size of the `Vec` into uninitialized memory. The values are whatever happens to be there already.

So let's look at some of the code:

```
let mut data = data.to_vec();
```

This copies the data "lorem ipsum." onto the heap in the form of a vector.

```
data.resize(data_len, 2); // data_len = 16
```

This increases the capacity of the `Vec` from 12 to 16 items, which happen to be bytes in this case. But actually, based on what we are seeing, it looks like the implementation (or possibly the optimiser) decided it was better to just abandon the first allocated memory range and copy the data to new memory instead.

```
let mut output = Vec::<u8>::with_capacity(data_len);
unsafe { output.set_len(data_len) }
```

This creates a new vector and *unsafely* gives it a length. But you didn't initialise it, so the data will be what was there previously.

It looks like `data.resize()` actually copied the value instead of just dropping the end of the vector. When `output` was allocated, it was allocated the same block of memory that was previously used, which is why it contains `"lorem ipsum."`.

Comment: But why does the `data.resize(data_len, 2);` line trigger this behaviour? If it's commented the `output` vector is full of zeroes.

Comment: `data.resize` probably allocates new storage with the requested length, copies the data over, then frees the old storage. When `output` is created, it looks like it reuses the old storage for the `data` vector.

Comment: @FrancisGagné https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.resize "Resizes the Vec in-place so that len() is equal to new_len."

Comment: @zerkms I'm not sure about the documentation here, but at some point it has to allocate. If it's longer than the old capacity it can't be *in place*. Probably a documentation bug (or at least not clear enough). If you look in [the source code](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/collections/vec.rs.html#1196-1208) you can see that `reserve()` will be called.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt yep, and in this case the new length is less, so it must truncate.

Comment: The "in-place" probably refers to the `Vec` itself. The `Vec` is not moved, only the pointer inside the `Vec` might get a new value.

Comment: @Shepmaster then it makes very little sense. In-place operation for collections is an established term, that means that it's sub-linear in terms of memory.